# XCOM - Win 2019 compatibility using old version of XCOM

Tags: airflow-xcom

The company I work for uses XCOM to send files to an external service provider to disburse money to clients.

We have a windows service running in production, on a Windows 2012 server, with XCOM installed on it. Everything works fine.

The company has decided to decommission the old servers and upgrade to Windows 2019 servers.

I now have our "disbursement" windows service running on the 2019 server. I am trying to call the xcomtcp.exe on the 2012 server, but I was told by our "money disbursement" provider that XCOM needs to be installed on both the server where the "disbursement" windows service (2019 Server) in running as well as on the server where XCOM is currently running (2012 Server), in order for me to call the xcomtcp.exe on the server (2019), from the windows service server (2012).

I have never worked with XCOM before and just wanted to verify that what the external provider told us, is indeed correct.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Thanks.